# How can I show that the language is regular using the closure properties?

Tags: regular-language

How can I show that the language $L=\{ w \in \{a,b\}^*: \text{ the word w contains an even number of a and an odd number of b} \}$ is regular using the closure properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $A$ is the set of words that have an even number of `a`s, and $B$ is the set of words that have an odd number of `b`s.  Then $L = A\cap B$. Do you know anything about regular languages and intersections?

Comment: Ok..And since regular languages are closed under the intersection, $L$ is regular, right? Are the languages $A$ and $B$ known to be regular,or do I have to prove it first?

Comment: You have to prove it first.

Comment: Do I have to prove it by constructing a DFA? Or could I also find a regular expression for the language? Is such an expression for $A$: $\{aa\}^*$ and for $B$: $  b | \{bbb\}^* $ ?

Comment: Those are not the right expressions.  Language $A$ includes the word `aba`, and language $B$ includes the word `bbbbb`.

Comment: Oh, yes..you're right! Is it maybe something like that for $A$: $(b^*ab^*ab^*)^* $ ?